# Is this a correct BubbleSort Algorithm?

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I wrote the following code to sort the elements in the array values using a BubbleSort. Is this correct or is there anything missing? My test cases are good, but maybe it's the test cases that are also missing something.

```
public void sort(ValuePair[] values) {

    ValuePair value = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1 + i; j < values.length; j++) {
            if (values[i].getValue() > values[j].getValue()) {
                value = values[j];
                values[j] = values[i];
                values[i] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you should move this post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, if you test cases worked, then why do you think it is not correct?  See this [link](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/bubble-sort)

Comment: Looks like a bubble sort to me. Missing in what sense?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Seems fine ...how does the output differs from the desired output?

Comment: how is stackexchange diffrnt from stackoverflow??

Comment: Friends don't let friends use bubble sort.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct in that it will sort the array. However it will always require N*(N-1) passes over the array. This is not 
the typical algorithm used to implement 
a bubble sort. The typical algorithm uses repeat loop with a test for sorted. This is somewhat more efficient because it
terminates as soon as the array is sorted (consider the case where you start with a sorted array).

Read the [Wikepedia article on bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) it demonstrates this very well.

A somewhat improved version pseudocode version of Bubble Sort goes something like this:

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
    n = length(A)
    repeat
       swapped = false
       for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
          if A[i-1] > A[i] then
             swap(A[i-1], A[i])
             swapped = true
          end if
       end for
       n = n - 1
    until not swapped
end procedure
```

The lesson here is that while your algorithm and the Wikepedia algorithm both have the same big O characteristics, a small change
in the way they have been implemented can make a significant difference in their actual performance characteristics.